# Grails plugin: inject list into bean inside doWithSpring

Tags: spring, grails, grails-plugin

I have a bean with a List property.
As it's mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.grails.org/3.3.3/guide/spring.html#theBeanBuilderDSLExplained) you can easily inject List property to the bean using beans DSL:

```
def example = exampleBean(MyExampleBean) {
        someProperty = [1, 2, 3]
    }
```

It works in `resources.groovy`, but if you do it in plugin's `doWithSpring` closure - the same bean definition doesn't work.

Is that a Grails bug (I'm using Grails 3.3.3)? Are there any workarounds to make it work in the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/taraskahut.

The plugin descriptor at https://github.com/jeffbrown/taraskahut/blob/df3df67cb8a6dd24317f45aa51b6fff449b60ed1/helper/src/main/groovy/helper/HelperGrailsPlugin.groovy#L43-L48 contains the following:

```
    Closure doWithSpring() { {->
            exampleBean(MyExampleBean) {
                someProperty = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
            }
        }
    }
```

The `BootStrap.groovy` in the app at https://github.com/jeffbrown/taraskahut/blob/df3df67cb8a6dd24317f45aa51b6fff449b60ed1/app/grails-app/init/app/BootStrap.groovy contains the following:

```
package app

import helper.MyExampleBean

class BootStrap {

    MyExampleBean exampleBean

    def init = { servletContext ->
        log.debug "someProperty is ${exampleBean.someProperty}"
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Running the app demonstrates that the property initialization works as expected:

```
$ ./gradlew app:bootRun
...
:app:processResources
:app:classes
:app:findMainClass
:app:bootRun
2018-11-06 13:19:52.983 DEBUG --- [           main] app.BootStrap
    : someProperty is [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
```

Comment: Thanks, Jeff, your example works. I use the same structure in my project, and for some reason, it still doesn't inject the list in a plugin. Btw I'm injecting into a service. Probably I'm missing something. Anyway, I fixed it using a workaround: after defining a list bean separately using ListFactoryBean it injects it fine.